# Extrapolate the curve of a stroke join

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

Is there a plugin or any other way to make sharp edges of an offset path command or stroke behave like the **Extrapolate** example in the image below?

[image: example]

I have searched but have found nothing so far.

Currently, I use a **Miter Join**  and need to fix all of the sharp joins manually to create a nice curved join.

[image]

Comment: This is why I always use an inside stroke in these situations. I'm not sure if it's even possible with an actual stroke. It is probably possible with a script if you don't mind outlining the stroke though.

Comment: [Related discussion on Adobe Forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1109045)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!
Actually at this case is required outside offset path, actually I have searched for such script but still without result.

Answer (score 4):

Extending a bezier path is possible, so yes this is possible.  If you are willing to build the path extension yourself then path extension is available in the [vectorscribe](http://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) plugin. Easiest is to just use a miter join and then delete the miter segment and extend.

I dont know any that work directly at offset although that is certainly possible to do. Its just that extrapolating is not always a good idea as there are a infinite possible extensions.

Comment: Do you use vectorscribe? So many people have recommended it to me—I've been debating getting it for a long time.

Comment: @CAI Simply put, No. I don't use vector scribe but it s useful. Vector scribe mostly shows what the basic flaw in Adobes tool set is. The simplify tool is the only one i miss really.

Comment: It definitely looks useful, I'm just not sure if it's useful enough (i.e will speed up my workflow enough) for me to pay for it :)

Comment: joojaa, I have tried the 1.9 version of vectorscribe but there are no such option/tool of path extension actually I think that such kind of join "extrapolate" when you use a stroke or offset path will be very useful for vector drawing workers, I have found this IMAGE ABOVE in website for SVG drawing language, so its possible but there is no such written plugin or script.

Comment: Its called path extend tool, available in 2.0 and forward see link. Every cad application I have ever used has had this feature. Simply because any meaningfull 3d offset is not possible without one. I dont dispute that it would be useful, but i cant help you with a tool for this simply because you  (most likely) couldnt afford to hire me making it for you.